# How can I use bugpoint to isolate code passes?

Tags: llvm

I have an LLVM IR source file that changes behaviour when I optimise it. I want to know which LLVM pass is causing this.

This is the expected behaviour, factoring numbers on stdin:

```
$ wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Wilfred/dde83b701d9bb8d7207a/raw/3eea89526ded7efa995f5bda89012b526dd49691/with_zeroing.ll        
$ echo 1337 | lli with_zeroing.ll 
1337: 7 191
```

After running through `opt`, it just echoes the original number:

```
$ opt -S -O2 with_zeroing.ll -o with_zeroing_o2.ll
$ echo 1337 | lli with_zeroing_o2.ll              
1337: 1337
```

How can I use `bugpoint` to work out which optimisation pass is changing this behaviour?

I've tried `bugpoint with_zeroing.ll -llc-safe` but I think I need a way of piping input into the resulting compiled binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LLVM bug report document [has a great section on optimisation bugs](http://llvm.org/docs/HowToSubmitABug.html#compile-time-optimization-bugs).

First, find out which passes are being run by `opt` on your code:

```
$ opt -O2 -debug-pass=Arguments with_zeroing.ll -disable-output
Pass Arguments:  -tti -no-aa -tbaa -scoped-noalias -assumption-cache-tracker -targetlibinfo -basicaa -verify -simplifycfg -domtree -sroa -early-cse -lower-expect
Pass Arguments:  -targetlibinfo -tti -no-aa -tbaa -scoped-noalias -assumption-cache-tracker -basicaa -ipsccp -globalopt -deadargelim -domtree -instcombine -simplifycfg -basiccg -prune-eh -inline-cost -inline -functionattrs -domtree -sroa -early-cse -lazy-value-info -jump-threading -correlated-propagation -simplifycfg -domtree -instcombine -tailcallelim -simplifycfg -reassociate -domtree -loops -loop-simplify -lcssa -loop-rotate -licm -loop-unswitch -instcombine -scalar-evolution -loop-simplify -lcssa -indvars -loop-idiom -loop-deletion -loop-unroll -mldst-motion -domtree -memdep -gvn -memdep -memcpyopt -sccp -domtree -bdce -instcombine -lazy-value-info -jump-threading -correlated-propagation -domtree -memdep -dse -loops -loop-simplify -lcssa -licm -adce -simplifycfg -domtree -instcombine -barrier -float2int -domtree -loops -loop-simplify -lcssa -loop-rotate -branch-prob -block-freq -scalar-evolution -loop-accesses -loop-vectorize -instcombine -scalar-evolution -slp-vectorizer -simplifycfg -domtree -instcombine -loops -loop-simplify -lcssa -scalar-evolution -loop-unroll -instcombine -loop-simplify -lcssa -licm -scalar-evolution -alignment-from-assumptions -strip-dead-prototypes -elim-avail-extern -globaldce -constmerge -verify
```

Next, call bugpoint using `-input` to specify the input to your program:

```
$ echo "1337" > input.txt
$ bugpoint with_zeroing.ll -input input.txt -run-int \
         -targetlibinfo -tti -no-aa -tbaa -scoped-noalias -assumption-cache-tracker -basicaa -ipsccp -globalopt -deadargelim -domtree -instcombine -simplifycfg -basiccg -prune-eh -inline-cost -inline -functionattrs -domtree -sroa -early-cse -lazy-value-info -jump-threading -correlated-propagation -simplifycfg -domtree -instcombine -tailcallelim -simplifycfg -reassociate -domtree -loops -loop-simplify -lcssa -loop-rotate -licm -loop-unswitch -instcombine -scalar-evolution -loop-simplify -lcssa -indvars -loop-idiom -loop-deletion -loop-unroll -mldst-motion -domtree -memdep -gvn -memdep -memcpyopt -sccp -domtree -bdce -instcombine -lazy-value-info -jump-threading -correlated-propagation -domtree -memdep -dse -loops -loop-simplify -lcssa -licm -adce -simplifycfg -domtree -instcombine -barrier -float2int -domtree -loops -loop-simplify -lcssa -loop-rotate -branch-prob -block-freq -scalar-evolution -loop-accesses -loop-vectorize -instcombine -scalar-evolution -slp-vectorizer -simplifycfg -domtree -instcombine -loops -loop-simplify -lcssa -scalar-evolution -loop-unroll -instcombine -loop-simplify -lcssa -licm -scalar-evolution -alignment-from-assumptions -strip-dead-prototypes -elim-avail-extern -globaldce -constmerge -verify
```